# ecs-cli compose service up doesn't terminate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I want to build a script to deploy a docker container to ecs.

This is the command I am using.

```
ecs-cli compose --file src/main/docker/docker-compose-export.yml -p export service up
```

It works about 60% of the time. The other 40% of the time the command stalls.

This is the compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  export:
    image: 1234567890lalala.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/export:${VERSION}
    cpu_shares: 200
    mem_limit: 100000000
```

I have uploaded the image to the ecs registry before.

This is the log I am getting:

```
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option...           option name=networks
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=export
INFO[0000] Using ECS task definition                     TaskDefinition="ecscompose-export:3"
INFO[0000] Updated the ECS service with a new task definition. Old containers will be stopped automatically, and replaced with new ones  desiredCount=1 serviceName=ecscompose-service-export taskDefinition="ecscompose-export:3"
INFO[0000] Describe ECS Service status                   desiredCount=1 runningCount=1 serviceName=ecscompose-service-export
INFO[0030] Describe ECS Service status                   desiredCount=1 runningCount=1 serviceName=ecscompose-service-export
INFO[0061] Describe ECS Service status                   desiredCount=1 runningCount=1 serviceName=ecscompose-service-export
INFO[0091] Describe ECS Service status                   desiredCount=1 runningCount=1 serviceName=ecscompose-service-export
```

The running count goes to 2 and then back to 1 (which is expected). But then it does not stop like it does when everything works but it keeps checking the status a while and finally just stalls.

The service on the cluster is in a good state. The new docker image is running and everything is find. Its just that the command doesn't stop.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this? Are there maybe other commands that I could use to achieve the same in a more reliable fashion?